# Call a function just after ajax call is sent

Tags: ajax, axios

I have to show a message "Request for execution sent" after the ajax call is made but before the response is received in axios.

```
axios
  .post('executeTask', {
    id,
    status,
    name
  })
  .then(response => {

  })
  .catch(error => {

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show message before handling your promise:

```
var promise = axios
  .post('executeTask', {
    id,
    status,
    name
  });

  // show message here


  promise.then(response => {

  })
  .catch(error => {

  });
```